# Flutter: Ternary Condition is not working

Tags: flutter, dart, visibility, ternary

I am trying to create a condition for `Visibility()` widget. I already trying this by two way. Where in `1st way` by 2nd condition is working perfectly but first condition isn't working.

Same as in 2nd way my 2nd condition is working perfectly but 1st and 3rd condition isn't working.

I also checked string value and id value it's okay.

Please someone describe me, what is the problem

> **1st way**

```
Visibility(
                  visible: (_educationLevelName == "H.S.C or Equivalent" &&
                              (examinationNameID != 8 || //1st condition
                                  examinationNameID != 11)) ||
                          (_educationLevelName == "S.S.C or Equivalent" &&
                              examinationNameID != 3) //2nd condition
                      ? true
                      : false,
                  child: Container()
                   
                ),
```

> **2nd way:**

```
Visibility(
                  visible: (_educationLevelName == "H.S.C or Equivalent" &&
                              examinationNameID !=
                                  8) || //<<================== //1st condition
                          (_educationLevelName == "S.S.C or Equivalent" &&
                              examinationNameID !=
                                  3) || //<<================== //2nd condition

                          (_educationLevelName == "H.S.C or Equivalent" &&
                              examinationNameID !=
                                  11) //<<================== //3rd condition
                      ? true
                      : false,
                  child: Container(),
                ),
```

You can check in on  [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/1fbedf5f1c12ac5122b141cd33b33749)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right here are your 3 condition :

1. _educationLevelName == "H.S.C or Equivalent" && examinationNameID != 8
2. _educationLevelName == "S.S.C or Equivalent" && examinationNameID != 3
3. _educationLevelName == "H.S.C or Equivalent" && examinationNameID != 11

Which you simplify to :

1. _educationLevelName == "H.S.C or Equivalent" && (examinationNameID != 8 || examinationNameID != 11)
2. _educationLevelName == "S.S.C or Equivalent" && examinationNameID != 3

I think your condition is wrong, this might be better :

1. _educationLevelName == "H.S.C or Equivalent" && (examinationNameID != 8 && examinationNameID != 11)
2. _educationLevelName == "S.S.C or Equivalent" && examinationNameID != 3

**Case 1 :**

```
  String _educationLevelName = "H.S.C or Equivalent";
  int examinationNameID = 8;
```

=> not displayed because of condition must be "H.S.C or Equivalent" AND id !=(8 AND 11)

**Case 2 :**

```
  String _educationLevelName = "H.S.C or Equivalent";
  int examinationNameID = 3;
```

=> displayed

By the way you can simplify you code (remove the true/false because you are already checking boolean) :

```
Visibility(
                  visible: (_educationLevelName == "H.S.C or Equivalent" &&
                              (examinationNameID != 8 && examinationNameID != 11)) 
                          || (_educationLevelName == "S.S.C or Equivalent" && examinationNameID != 3),
                  child: Container()
                   
                ),
```

Comment: Please can you check this DartPad url  https://dartpad.dev/1fbedf5f1c12ac5122b141cd33b33749

Comment: I did, I updated my answer. I think your condition might be wrong

Answer (score 1):

It can be written in this way for easy understanding

```
  String lvl = 'hsc';
  int year = 8;

  bool isValidForHsc = lvl == 'hsc' && ![8, 11].contains(year);
  bool isValidForSsc = lvl == 'ssc' && year != 3;
  
  print('$lvl - $year');
  print('isValidForHsc - $isValidForHsc');
  print('isValidForSsc - $isValidForSsc');
```

Otherwise, you can combine the logic this way

```
  bool isValid = (lvl == 'hsc' && ![8, 11].contains(year)) || (lvl == 'ssc' && year != 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a boolean function or getter that computes all of the conditions after that you can use either:

```
if(condition)
Container(
 child: .....
)
```

or

```
condition ? Container(child: ...) : Container()
```

where the 2nd container is empty.

Comment: if()else() condition will not working in widget(), and at first I tried your 2nd way. Then go to  Visibility()

Comment: what do you mean if() condition will not work in widget can you share the code that does not work

Comment: The element type 'Set<Container>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your ternary and I think you used `||` instead of `&&` in `educationLevelName == "H.S.C or Equivalent" && (examinationNameID != 8 || examinationNameID != 11)`. If I understood your condition correctly it should be true if `examinationNameID` is not 8 or 11 then you should use the `&&` operator.

Here is a small refacto I've done to your code to separate your condition and fix it:

```dart
bool isVisible(String educationLevelName, int examinationNameID) =>
    (educationLevelName == "H.S.C or Equivalent" &&
        (examinationNameID != 8 && examinationNameID != 11)) ||
    (educationLevelName == "S.S.C or Equivalent" && examinationNameID != 3);
```

I've also made some unit tests to check the return values expected, you can [try it on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/e41f807e3736b68a18db7d7d6ed4363e).

Comment: Actually here is not 2 conditions but also 3 conditions what I described in 2nd way

Comment: He combined the last condition with the first one since a part of it is redundant

Comment: can you please check this url https://dartpad.dev/1fbedf5f1c12ac5122b141cd33b33749